# Advice on writing a search function with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, design-patterns, search

I am developing a web application, part of which contains a the ability to allow a user to search over multiple fields across 7 tables in a database.

Users can search (for example)

First Name - text
Last Name - text
Height - select
Age Minumum- select
Age Maximum- select
Favourite Color - select
College - select

...and many many more

The HTML search form will contain text fields, many select dropdowns and some checkboxes.

Can anyone offer any advice, best practice, design patterns or resources to assist with this kind of problem.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I would go with Zend_Search_Lucene or other search engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `LIKE` operator in sql and wildcard search characters.

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM
  users
WHERE
  first_name LIKE '%".$first_name."%' ||
  age > '".$age."'
```

Comment: But please use placeholders or something to prevent SQL injection.  http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try to build a keyword search feature in SQL.  You should read up on MySQL's built-in full-text search feature.  Attempting a comprehensive search through basic SQL will be time consuming to develop and sluggish at runtime.

The basic idea of a full-text search is a combination of two systems. First, the Indexer, which reads your database for keywords and creates an "Index" of them. Second, the Searcher, which looks through the catalog created by the Indexer to create search results.

There are third party tools - Lucene, Xapian, Sphinx - which package their own Indexer/Searcher.  I have used Xapian to some success.

Comment: yes I see what you mean, but in this instance they will not be searching through any large blocks of text, so this might be overkill most of the fields will be == instead of LIKE

Comment: You're right. I didn't read the question carefully enough.  Your UI is specific enough that a SQL search shouldn't be too bad.

Answer (score 0):

> The HTML search form will contain text fields, many select dropdowns and some checkboxes.
>   Can anyone offer any advice, best practice, design patterns or resources to assist with this kind of problem.

I would suggest that Google exemplifies the best UI for search.  Don't give me a lot of fiddly fields, just one text field so I can type "Shirley Jones UAF"

Comment: unfortunately that does not answer the question at all. Google's search is predominately searching large blocks of text for keywords. Mine is nothing like that.

Comment: Are you sure your users would prefer the more complicated form?  Most sites these days have a single field text search in the upper right, maybe with an "advanced search" that users hardly ever use.

Comment: its quite a specific web app allowing people to select individuals for jobs based on a number of criteria